# Handle unauthorized error message for Basic Authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security 3.0.5 in my web application. Basically, I want to have a web service which return data in json format via `HTTP GET`.

I have implemented a RESTful service which returns data when the url `http://localhost:8080/webapp/json` is requested. This works fine with the following curl command

```
> curl http://localhost:8080/webapp/json
{"key":"values"}
```

After I added basic authentication using spring security, I can use following commands to get the data

```
> curl  http://localhost:8080/webapp/json
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 - Error report .....
> curl -u username:password http://localhost:8080/webapp/json
{"key":"values"}
```

The former command returns standard tomcat error page since now it requires username and password. **My question is whether it is possible to handle access denied in such a way that it prints out my own error message?** i.e.

```
> curl  http://localhost:8080/webapp/json
{"error":"401", "message":"Username and password required"}
```

Here is my spring security configuration and `AccessDeniedHandler`. As you can see, I am trying to add `access-denied-handler` which simply prints out a string through servlet response but it still does not print my own message on command line.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <beans:bean name="access-denied" class="webapp.error.JSONAccessDeniedHandler"></beans:bean>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <access-denied-handler ref="access-denied"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/json" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"  />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            <user-service>
            ...
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

`AccessDeniedHandler.java`

```
package webapp.error;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;

public class JSONAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler  {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.print("{\"error\":\"401\", \"message\":\"Username and password required\"}");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you check the output of curl -S or curl -v ?

Comment: I have modified my question. It wasn't printing nothing but it doesn't print what I want. The curl -S and curl -v both print standard tomcat 401 error page. -v has more details of the request/response

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have solved my problem so I think I should share it here. This configuration allows server to send out error message differently depending on the requesting software. If the request comes from a web browser, it will check the `User-Agent` header and redirect to a form login if necessary. If the request comes from, for example, `curl`, it will print out plain text error message when the authentication fails.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- AspectJ pointcut expression that locates our "post" method and applies security that way
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* bigbank.*Service.post*(..))" access="ROLE_TELLER"/>-->
    <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter"
          p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager"
          p:authenticationEntryPoint-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="webapp.PlainTextBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          p:realmName="myWebapp"/>

    <bean id="formAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          p:loginFormUrl="/login.jsp"/>

    <bean id="daep" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="hasHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla') or hasHeader('User-Agent','Opera') or hasHeader('User-Agent','Explorer')" value-ref="formAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="defaultEntryPoint" ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    </bean>

    <sec:http entry-point-ref="daep">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/json" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"  />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/json/*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"  />
        <sec:logout
            logout-url="/logout"
            logout-success-url="/home.jsp"/>
        <sec:form-login
            login-page="/login.jsp"
            login-processing-url="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1" default-target-url="/home.jsp"/>
        <sec:custom-filter position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider>
        ...
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

`PlainTextBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` by extending `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;

public class PlainTextBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + getRealmName() + "\"");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status " + HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED + " - " + authException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if it is ever making it to your AccessDeniedHandler. Is the error because of Authentication or Authorization? Does the AccessDeniedHandeler get called for both scenarios? I am in the process of solving this myself right now.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't make to AccessDeniedHandler because it is still in Authentication or Authorization processes.

Comment: I have sort of solved this. Spring Security punts on it and hands it back out to the 401 pages defined by your app in the web.xml. Well if you want to trap that, you have to write your own AuthenticationProcessFilter and handle the content type and error response there. I have noticed that some people are just letting the HTTP status be there error message, but I don't like that and will end up writing a CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter that looks at the original request extension or Accept Header and give back the appropriate response.

Comment: I have solve it slightly differently but it is fairly powerful that allow me to have form login at the same time. I have posted below. If you share your code, it may be very helpful