# Different Login pages for mobile and desktop while using Spring Security

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security, mobile-application

I'm using spring-security web authentication with spring-mvc, all is well so far, but now i am developing a mobile version of my application for that i have designed a different set of pages for mobile site which includes a different login page. now my i have problems configuring that

here's my applicationContext-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" lowercase-comparisons="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Stylesheets/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/JavaScript/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/mobile/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <form-login login-page="/login.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="customHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true" default-target-url="/home.htm"
            login-processing-url="/j_security_check"  />
         <remember-me user-service-ref="userDAO" key="e37f4b31-0c46-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="customHandler" class="com.example.auth.AuthenticationHandler">
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDAO">
            <!--
            TODO skipped to allow password emailing instead of password change and security
            TODO question hell..
          -->
           <!--  <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>  -->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

now how can i have multiple login pages according to the different request, i mean if the pages of mobile folder than the user should be shown the mobile login page. 
i have seen similar questions on stackoverflow but those were login pages according to different roles, but in my case i want diff login for different pages.

hi, thanks for the solution it seems that it will work fine for me. i have now switched to spring security 3.1 but it is giving me an exception. can you please help me resolve this.

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required for bean '(inner bean)#7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the posibility to switch t spring security 3.1, you can simply define 2 http elements [1](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/new-3.1.html#new-3.1-ns). If you can not switch, you can not configure it fully via the namespace, but have to register an entry-point-ref and somd `<sec:custom-filter>` elements.

Comment: hi, thanks for the solution it seems that it will work fine for me. i have now switched to spring security 3.1 but it is giving me an exception. can you please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide a custom [authentication entry point](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#exception-translation-filter) and make a decision there. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4477459/53949) could be a starting point you can use.