# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I just switched to Spring security 3.1 because I was facing this issue "[Different Login pages for mobile and desktop while using Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615067/different-login-pages-for-mobile-and-desktop-while-using-spring-security)"

So I got a solution to switch to spring security 3.1 now I am facing this new **exception while running the application.**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required for bean '(inner bean)#7'
```

My applicationContext looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
default-lazy-init="true">

<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config />

 <!-- Activates scanning of @Repository -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao.user"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.model"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service.impl"/>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

and my applicationContext-security.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
      <security:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
      <security:http pattern="/Stylesheets/**" security="none"/>
      <security:http pattern="/JavaScript/**" security="none"/>
      <security:http pattern="/scripts/**" security="none"/>

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/passwordHint*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/signup*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home.htm" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/changepwd.htm" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pwd.htm*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="customHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true" default-target-url="/home.htm"
        login-processing-url="/j_security_check"  />
     <security:remember-me user-service-ref="userDAO" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
</security:http>    

 <security:http auto-config="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/passwordHint*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/signup*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/login.htm" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/home.htm" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/changepwd.htm" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/pwd.htm*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="mobile/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/mlogin.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="customHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/mlogin.htm?error=true" default-target-url="/mhome.htm"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"  />
     <security:remember-me user-service-ref="userDAO" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="customHandler" class="com.example.auth.AuthenticationHandler">
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDAO">
        <!--
        TODO skipped to allow password emailing instead of password change and security
        TODO question hell..
      -->
       <!--  <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>  -->
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Is anything wrong in these configurations?

Comment: Can you provide "userDAO" bean definition?

Comment: It does appear that the userDAO definition holds the root cause. Something in that definition requires a `sessionFactory` property, but is not getting it.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting the same BeanCreationException with DefaultSecurityFilterChain

Comment: Based on the log, the error is not related to spring security config, double check if sessionFactory bean is injected correctly into your dao beans.

Answer (score -1):

Can you give the complete exception stack trace? I don't think you can have two

```
<security:http auto-config="true"/>
```

in the same spring-security configuration with all the intercept-url settings. If you need to have two separate login pages have an attribute in the login request or use the "userAgent" and do the switching in the controller.