# Basic authentication in Grails 3.0.4 with Spring Security

Tags: angularjs, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to do Base authentication with Grails 3.0 an AngularJS.

Firstly in `build.gradle` I added Spring Security plugin (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/index.html):

```
 compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'
```

Then I configured `application.yml`

```
grails:
  plugin:
    springsecurity:
      useBasicAuth: true
      basic:
        realmName: "xxx"
      userLookup:
        userDomainClassName: xxx
      rejectIfNoRule: true
      fii:
        rejectPublicInvocations: false
      controllerAnnotations:
        staticRules: [... ommited ...]
```

In angular service I've created this method:

```
var authenticateOwner = function (credentials, callback) {

            var headers = credentials ? {authorization: "Basic " + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)} : {};

            $http.get('/login/owner', {headers: headers}).success(function (data) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = !!data.basicUserInfo.name;
                callback && callback();
            }).error(function () {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                callback && callback();
            });

        };
```

In module confid I added `X-Requested-With` header to prevent `WWW-Authenticate` coming back:

```
angular.module([...]).config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        });
```

The problem is that in response I getting `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="xxx"` header which makes browser to show the log in dialog. 
So how can I make proper login with AngulrJS & Grails?

PS 
I'm using this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ to develop login in Grails.

Comment: Could you share the filter where you will perform the actual authentication. meaning, where you are injectiong your authenticationManager

Comment: you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617073/spring-security-rest-basic-authentication-issue but as Sudakatux mentioned, it is an issue with the filter

Comment: I do not any filter (more specyfic: I didn't create any filter, maybe Spring Security/Grails Plugin created one)